# ServiceStack IHttpRequest.AbsoluteUri does not matched browser client Uri

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack, request.servervariables

I have an authentication provider that uses HMAC as an authentication mechanism in ServiceStack.

I am using `IHttpRequest.AbsoluteUri` to grab the `Uri`, but the `Uri` isn't what I expected. As `Uri` is a core part of the HMAC base string I'm using for the HMAC, the authentication is failing on our pre-production servers.

```
private string BuildBaseString(IHttpRequest req, string accountCode, string username, string timestamp)
{
    var methodType = req.HttpMethod;
    var absoluteUri = req.AbsoluteUri;
    return string.Join("\n", methodType, timestamp, absoluteUri, accountCode, username).ToUpper();
}
```

I am logging everything using ServiceStack's awesome logging feature. My assumption was that the URL entered in the REST client, would be the same as the `IHttpRequest.AbsoluteUri`. However, there is a small but significant difference, which I assume is due to a load balancer.

```
https://service.com/auth/hmac
```

is being converted to the AbsoluteUri:

```
https://service.com:80/auth/hmac
```

(I can see this in the ServiceStack logs)

The question is, is there a better `IHttpRequest` property I should be using to avoid this, or do I need to manually break out the Uri myself in C# to strip out the port number? The latter seems a bit hacky.

Update:

I know this would work, but is there a better way?

```
var req = authService.RequestContext.Get<IHttpRequest>();
var u = new System.Uri(req.AbsoluteUrl); // https://service.com:80/auth/hmac
string clean = u.GetComponents( UriComponents.AbsoluteUri & ~UriComponents.Port, UriFormat.UriEscaped );
Console.WriteLine(clean); // https://service.com/auth/hmac
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your client end C# too (like in a controller). If so, then you can create a new System.Uri from your other URL (without the port number) and then do a ToString on that.

In that way, you'll be able to directly compare the URLs using the same parsing. Better than stripping the port, because it allows for differing port numbers being different.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. The client assumes no port. The server AbsoluteUri returns the Uri with a port. Are you suggesting: `var u1 = new UriBuilder(req.AbsoluteUri); string clean = u1.Uri.ToString();` because that includes the port too? 

Mainly because of this: "The string returned by this method does not contain port information when the port is the default port for the scheme." (msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.tostring.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I'm suggesting that both Uri's in the compare be instantiated as System.Uri. The note on the port number not being returned is not relevant, because identical Urls would be rendered in precisely the same manner, displaying or withholding port number as per the rules of the method. If they render differently, then there must be a difference.

Comment: I guess that was the point of my question. The load balancer deliberately adds the port into the request URI. The initial request made by the client doesn't specify the port so the process fails. MY suggested solution is above, but I was looking for improvements for this, specifically solutions that are already built into the ServiceStack IHttpRequest, which is a loose wrapper around Http.Current.Request